# SQL Server : compare data in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, sum

My DB is SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Here is my table:

```
  DATE            F1          F2        F3
2015-07-1         32           5        78
2015-08-20        18          45        67
2015-09-1         64           9        80
2015-09-30        12          78        45
```

Now I would like to count the sum and select only the difference value between last and current month, so in this example selected data should be between August and September, so for example for the field `F1` it will take the unique value for the August which is 18 then two values from September 64+12=76, then count the difference 76-18, so the value of the `F1` should be 58.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example you state other figures than in your text, at least they are not beside the month you mention... Could you please create a table with your expected output with the given data above?

Comment: Hi Shnugo, I have edited my post. Months are August and September.

Comment: Which db you are using?

Comment: My DB is MSSQL 2012 SP1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select


    sum(case when Month(date) = month(curdatde()) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F1 else null end)- sum(case when Month(date) = (month(curdatde())-1) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F1 else null end) as'F1',
     sum(case when Month(date) = month(curdatde()) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F2 else null end)- sum(case when Month(date) = (month(curdatde())-1) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F2 else null end) as'F2', 
    sum(case when Month(date) = month(curdatde()) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F3 else null end)- sum(case when Month(date) = (month(curdatde())-1) and  Year(date) = Year(curdatde()) then F3 else null end) as'F3' from your table
```

This works for mySql

Answer (score 0):

This is probably over engineered, but I think it does what you want. I'm calling your table "example_data". The first CTE (summed_data) groups your data by month and sums up the F columns. The second CTE then orders it all and takes only the most recent two months (so this does assume you don't have future data). It uses ROW_NUMBER() to assign 1 to the current month and 2 to the previous month. Then in the final SELECT, it joins the result of that second CTE on itself. Using the row identifiers to identify the current and prior months, it then takes the difference of each column.

```
WITH summed_data (some_date, f1, f2, f3)
AS
(
  SELECT MAX(some_date), SUM(f1), SUM(f2), SUM(f3)
    FROM example_data
  GROUP BY MONTH(some_date), YEAR(some_date)
),
last_two_months (row_number, f1, f2, f3)
AS 
(
  SELECT TOP 2 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_date DESC), f1, f2, f3 
    FROM summed_data
  ORDER BY some_date DESC
)

SELECT CURRENT_MONTH.f1 - PRIOR_MONTH.f1, 
       CURRENT_MONTH.f2 - PRIOR_MONTH.f2, 
       CURRENT_MONTH.f3 - PRIOR_MONTH.f3
  FROM last_two_months CURRENT_MONTH, last_two_months PRIOR_MONTH
 WHERE CURRENT_MONTH.row_number = 1
   AND PRIOR_MONTH.row_number = 2
```